# Session properties and JWT claims can't be accessed with embre-simple-auth-token

Tags: ember.js, jwt, ember-simple-auth

I have a basic working authentication system in my Ember app. I can receive a JWT and my app will log me in. The problem is that I can't access anything with something like `this.get('session').get('data.id')` as shown in an example on ember-simple-auth's GitHub page.

Here's the response from my authentication request:

```
{token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImFiY…yMyJ9.X0O3xMVikn-5l9gXBU5a2XF6vlMmTzm4mCqUNA68e-A", test: "abc123"}
```

Here's the payload of the token:

```
{
  "id": "abc123"
}
```

Yet, calling `this.get('session').get('data.id')` doesn't return anything. I also tried other things like `this.get('session').get('id')`.

`this.get('session').get('data')` returns:

```
{"authenticated":{"authenticator":"authenticator:jwt","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImFiYzEyMyJ9.X0O3xMVikn-5l9gXBU5a2XF6vlMmTzm4mCqUNA68e-A","test":"abc123"}}
```

So there is technically a way to read `test` but it doesn't seem like the right way.

`this.get('session')` exists, but is empty. Setting properties work well and they can be accessed afterwards.

How do I access the claims? ember-simple-auth-token has a specific authenticator for JWT so I assume it should be able to read the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the decoded payload like this:

```
JSON.parse(atob(this.get('session.data.authenticated.token').split('.')[1]))
```

Which is talked about [in this issue](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token/issues/50).

**UPDATE**

Just looked at this again and realised that I might have misunderstood you.
The method I mentioned above is how to decode the claims from the token, however that's not how you would access the claims from templates/routes etc.

[Here is a good blog post](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/update-setting-a-current-user-property-with-ember-simple-auth/) that shows how to make the claims more easily accessible.

Basically whenever a user is authenticated, a property is added to the session which allows the claims to be accessed like `this.get('session.claims.id')`.

In the blog post a user is fetched from the api and saved as `session.account`. If you would rather just set the claims directly from the token to the session you can do this:

services/session-account.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { inject: { service }, RSVP } = Ember;
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  session: service('session'),
  store: service(),
  loadCurrentUser() {
    const token = this.get('session.data.authenticated.token');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(token)) {
      var claims = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
      this.set('session.claims', claims);
    }
  }
});
```

Hopefully that's more what you were looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is just another complicated way to achieve my goal. Why can't I just do `this.get('session').get(something)` to get access to the claims of my JWT? Shouldn't it be a basic feature?

Comment: Just added an update which I think is more what you were after : )